# How to validate xml file w/o DTD

Tags: php

I have an XML file to manipulate and am using a XSLT for processing. I want to validate the XML file initially before the XSLT transform. 
This is my code :

```
<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('somefile.xml');

$isValid = $doc->validate();

if(!$isValid) {
    echo "$doc is INVALID!";
}else{

$xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsldoc->load('somename.xslt');


$xslt = new XSLTProcessor();
$xslt->importStylesheet($xsldoc);


$result = $xslt->transformToDoc($doc);
$result->save('somefile.xml');
}
?>
```

But after running this php file I get following errors:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(): no DTD found! in C:\test.php on line 10

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMDocument could not be converted to string in C:\test.php on line 13
```

Wherein I don't have any DTD file to validate against, So how I can validate now?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by Validate? what are you trying to validate? DTD defines what you want to validate, so if you don't have a DTD, there is no validation language. An example for validation might be that its properly formatted XML.

Comment: You want to validate *what*? The syntax has already been validated when you loaded the file, otherwise it wouldn't have been loaded to begin with. The `validate` method is specifically to check against a DTD.

Comment: There are things other than DTDs (such as Schema and Relax NG) that you can validate against, but you still need to have the rules expressed in *some* form.

Comment: You can't validate if there is nothing to validate.

Comment: Sorry if my question didn't make any sense but I am trying to validate if there are any syntax errors or check if my xml is well formatted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are two levels of validation for a XML file. The first one is the XML syntax itself. A XML document that conforms to that rules is called "wellformed". You do this validation by loading the XML.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($file);
var_dump(libxml_get_errors());
```

Depending on your general error handling this can get more advanced. Be aware that here can be warnings and notices, too. DOMDocument has some automatic corrections.

The second level is the validation against specific rules for your XML format. This validation is only possible if you define the rules using a DTD, Schema oder RelaxNG.

Comment: Thanks ThomasWeinert, it worked! This is what I was looking for.